# rank of the matrices of the form $A+\lambda B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Could anyone help me for the following problems?

$1. $ If $A+\lambda B\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ where we can vary $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, has rank $r<n$ then what can we say about the rank of $A$ and $B$?

$2.$ If $im(B)\subseteq im(A)$ then what can be said about the rank of $A+\lambda B$, if it is given that rank of $A=p$

$3.$ is it possible that $rank(A)<rank(A+\lambda B)$ for some values of $\lambda$?

Thank you for help and hints and any suggestions

Comment: Just a few comments: if you allow $\lambda$ to be zero, then for the first question this implies that the rank of $A$ is $r$. For the third, choosing $B=A$ and $\lambda=-1$ gives you an affirmative answer.

Comment: thank you for your comment

Comment: Part 1. is vague. Are you saying that $A+ \lambda B$ has rank $r$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes for all $\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

Let $\lambda=0$ and have rank(A)=r. We can also reach the conclusion that $rank(B)\leq r$. If rank(B)=r'>r, then we know that B has an submatrix $B_0$ of order r', $det(B_0)\neq 0$.

We consider the corresponding submatrix of $A+\lambda B$ (we suppose it is $A_0+\lambda B_0$), and we know that $det(A_0+\lambda B_0)$ is a polynomial of degree r', which has at most r' zeros. But your $\lambda$ has infinite values, so there exists a $\lambda_0$ which makes $det(A_0+\lambda_0 B_0)\neq 0$. Thus, $rank(A+\lambda B)\geq r'>r$.

So the conclusion is $rank(A)=r$ and $rank(B)\leq r$ (You can easily find the example that $rank(B)<r$)

Q2:

$\alpha$ is an arbitrary vector in the vector space V. Because $Im(B)\subseteq Im(A)$, we have $A\alpha \in Im(A)$ and $B\alpha \in Im(A)$. So $(A+\lambda B)\alpha \in Im(A)$, and we have $Im(A+\lambda B)\subseteq Im(A)$. The conclusion is $rank(A+\lambda B)\leq p$.

Q3:

If this question is based on the second question, then we will give the negative answer from the proof above.

Comment: thank you for your explanation , regarding answer number $2$, can we conclude that rank of $A+\lambda B=p$ exactly?

Comment: No, you can just think about the situation $B=A, \lambda=-1$, as b00n heT said.

Comment: For 1., Suppose $\operatorname{rk}B = p$, then for sufficiently large $\lambda$, the matrix $B+ {1 \over \lambda A}$ will also have rank $p$, and hence so does $A + \lambda B$ from which we see that $p \le r$.

Comment: I see it, but I don't have any idea about that question yet....Can you prove $Im(B)\subseteq Im(A)$? @La Belle Noiseuse

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean the question here. I mean the question which you give a hyperlink above.